# ¿Cómo unir varias bases de datos con un for en R?

Tags: r, bucle-for, dataframe

Tengo la siguientes bases de datos

```
df1<-data.frame(primer=c(1,2,3,4,5),segundo=c("a","b","c","d","e"))
df2<-data.frame(primer=c(5,4,3,2,1),segundo=c("b","b","c","b","a"))
df3<-data.frame(primer=c(5,5,3,1,1),segundo=c("a","b","a","b","a"))
```

Y deseo unirlas, lo que uno haría es un simple `rbind`. De la siguiente manera.

```
rbind(df1,df2,df3)
```

Pero deseo hacerlo con un bucle. He intentado lo siguiente, pero es obvio que está mal.

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  tab <- get(paste0("df", i))
  f<-rbind(tab)
}
```

También he intentado esto:

```
f<-NA

for (i in 1:3) {
  tab <- get(paste0("df", i))
  f<-rbind(f,tab)
}
```

Pero me sale una observación más al inicio.

Por favor, podrían ayudarme en arreglar mi código.

**Muchas gracias de antemano**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casi lo tienes:

```
f <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:3) {
  tab <- get(paste0("df", i))
  f <- rbind(f, tab)
}
```

¿Que te faltaba?:

1. El objeto `f` final, debe ser un `data.frame`, hay que crearlo como tal: `f <- data.frame()`
2. Hay que ir agregando cada `df` a `f` mediante `f <- rbind(f, tab)`

Otra forma más compacta podría ser:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(ls(pattern='df\\d+'), get))
```

Es decir, obtenemos los nombres de objetos que coincidan con el patrón `df` + un número, generamos una lista de los mismos con `get` y luego aplicamos `rbind` a cada elemento.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio. Excelente apoyo.